# Open Distro Elasticsearch - Authenticate to Kibana with JWT

Tags: elasticsearch, jwt, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

I could get the open distro running with basic auth (using internal user database), now I need to use JWT tokens to authenticate to Kibana dashboard.

Elasticsearch config:

```
     basic_internal_auth_domain:
        http_enabled: false
        transport_enabled: true
        order: 4
        http_authenticator:
          type: basic
          challenge: true
        authentication_backend:
          type: intern
      proxy_auth_domain:
        http_enabled: false
        transport_enabled: false
        order: 3
        http_authenticator:
          type: proxy
          challenge: false
          config:
            user_header: "x-proxy-user"
            roles_header: "x-proxy-roles"
        authentication_backend:
          type: noop
      jwt_auth_domain:
        enabled: true
        http_enabled: true
        transport_enabled: true
        order: 0
        http_authenticator:
          type: jwt
          challenge: false
          config:
            signing_key: "EdzdXd5weiuSVFyddfjhjhfjjchJGRrZmpkayZPUA=="
            jwt_header: "Authorization"
            jwt_url_parameter: "token"
            roles_key: "roles"
            subject_key: "sub"
        authentication_backend:
          type: noop
```

Kibana Config:

```
server.name: kibana
server.port: 5601
server.host: "127.0.0.1"

elasticsearch.url: https://127.0.0.1:9200
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
elasticsearch.username: kibanaserver
elasticsearch.password: kibanaserver
elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: ["securitytenant","Authorization"]

opendistro_security.auth.type: "jwt"
opendistro_security.jwt.url_param: token

opendistro_security.multitenancy.enabled: true
opendistro_security.multitenancy.tenants.preferred: ["Private", "Global"]
opendistro_security.readonly_mode.roles: ["kibana_read_only"]
```

After this, when I open the http://localhost:5601?token=dfkhdfjdfhdjfhdhfkhdjfhjdhfjdhffdjhfdjhf, the auth fails, elasticsearch logs show this message -

> [c.a.o.s.h.HTTPBasicAuthenticator] [node-1] No 'Basic Authorization'
>   header, send 401 and 'WWW-Authenticate Basic'

I have followed the documentation thoroughly, yet there is very little material on the internet right now, it's still in the POC stages for most of the people I guess. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those who are looking for an answer - My JWT token was wrong, make sure you configure "iat", "nbf" and "exp" according to your server timings and not your local time.

Comment: @gauravmakwana The question has the working config snippets, the issue was with the wrong jwt config